# Need info regarding cheapest mobile connections and internet plans in Berlin

Tags: budget, cellphones, internet, berlin

What is the cheapest and reliable mobile network in Berlin? I may also ask what are the most effective Internet providers/connections in Berlin? I will be moving to Berlin for the very first time and so I need information regarding SIM cards/connections, best ISD rate tariff connections and also info regarding Internet (Good speed yet cheap) for Skyping.

Comment: I would also like to know about the internet providers. I would normally do skype and video chatting. Please suggest me best option to use internet in Germany.

Comment: this would be off-topic here as it's rather expat question then a travel one